# Create a map of only one country in DIVA-GIS

Tags: shapefile, diva-gis

I made a map of china with the places where the climate is suitable to plant Brussels sprouts.
The bounderies of China are in a shapefile. However the layer with the colormap showing where the climate is suitable goes beyond the boundaries of China and I only want a map of China. How can I fix this?

I'm completely new to GIS

Comment: Which GIS software and version are you using? It sounds like you want the **Clip** function which should only show the colourmap for China.